# How do I convert an R list to the equivalent Rpy2 object?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have an R object defined as

```
seasonal = list(order = c(0, 0, 0), period = scalar)
```

which I need to be converted in the equivalent object to be passed in Rpy2. Please help.

Comment: passed to what? Your problem description is not clear. You may want to spend a few more lines explaining exactly what you would like to do here.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. My issue is to have the line above translated to the proper line in Rpy2. I don't seem to be able to find any list vector object in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import ListVector, IntVector
# if the order of the element does not matter
seasonal = ListVector({'order': IntVector((0,0,0)), 'period': scalar})
# if the order matters
seasonal = ListVector([('order', IntVector([0,0,0])),
                       ('period', scalar)])
```

There is at least one mention of `ListVector` in the documentation:
http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/vector.html?highlight=listvector#assigning-python-style